# What key is S in 'noremap <S-j> :bn<CR> noremap <S-k> :bp<CR>' for vim

Tags: vim

What is the S in the vim keybinding below:

```
noremap <S-j> :bn<CR>
noremap <S-k> :bp<CR>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `S` means "shift".

Answer (score 2):

See `:help key-notation`.

FWIW, there are a few things wrong with those mappings:

- The `<S-j>` notation is unnecessarily complex: `J` and `K` are easier to read.
- `noremap` covers too many modes (normal, visual, and operator-pending) while the mappings are only useful in normal mode. `:help :nnoremap` should be used instead of `noremap`.
- `:help J` and `:help K` are pretty useful commands in their own right. Think again before overriding them.